# kubuntu 17.10 system requirements for a new installation

Tags: system-requirements

What are the system requirements for installing Kubuntu 17.10? 
I have a 32 bit system and would like to do a clean install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to

https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/

download the 32bit version get Wubi installer on Windows or unebtootin under windows and install the image to your USB and check if your computer is suitable.

Without telling about your hardware, there is not really much to say.

If it is too slow, try Xubuntu or Lubuntu.