# How do I install Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox with Ubuntu 16.04 as host? When I try installing it says there is not enough space

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

How do I install Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox with Ubuntu 16.04 as host?

When I try to do that I get this message

> You need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu.
>
> This computer has only 0.0 B.

[image: dialog box showing the disk space error]

Comment: Looks like a VirtualBox settings question, seems not much to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: You should increase the size of the virtual hard disk in the VM. 10 Gb is better, but if you plan to install many packages 16 Gb is even better.

Answer (score 1):

When installing Ubuntu in VirtualBox we should assign at least [as much virtual hard disk space as we need](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop). For Ubuntu >= 17.04 this would be at least 10 GB.

> We rarely need to be that tight in hard drive space and when assigning the minimum we will very soon be face with a [low hard drive space error](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=votes&q=free%20space%20boot).

So on installating we should choose to create a **dynamically allocated  hard disk file** (which for good reason is the default) which can be up to 2 TB:

[image]

This drive will only use as much physical space as needed (the 2 TB *Testing* drive is not yet in use):

[image]

So for a testing Ubuntu VM I usually allocate 25 to 30 GB dynamically growing disks but there is no harm done if you make it larger and it would be much more complicated to grow a too small disk later.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to configure virtual box and give it more storage space. Probably you gave it just a few megabytes. As the image says, give it at least 8.6 Gigas.