# Juju with FUJITSU Cloud Service K5

Tags: juju

I would like to use Juju with Fujitsu Cloud Service K5, is it possible?
I'm trying to add a openstack cloud using "juju add-cloud" but I don't know the API endpoint. Could it be one of [these](https://k5-doc.jp-east-1.paas.cloud.global.fujitsu.com/doc/en/iaas/document/api-endpoint-list/index.html)?

Edit:
I think K5 is not exposing openstack endpoints, so I do not think K5 can be added as an openstack cloud.
Is there any plan to support Fujitsu K5 like it does with AWS, Azure or Rackspace?

Comment: this doesn't look like it's directly related to ubuntu... perhaps ask on meta instead?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte If you mean [meta], it’s even worse target for this type of questions.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: This is most definitely on topic

Answer (score 0):

@Kroma, I would suggest to use MAAS+JUJU to deploy OpenStack.

Process would be as follows:

1) Deploy MAAS + add your Vms/physical servers to it.

2) Deploy JUJU and bootstrap with MAAS

3) Deploy OpenStack via JUJU (vm/machines will be provisioned via MAAS)

Also if you are trying to deploy OpenStack just to test funcionality, show others (play with it), my suggestion would be to use **conjure-up** https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/try-openstack