# Processor for Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: system-installation, hardware, system

The processor of my Desktop Computer is not suitable for 18.04 LTS. What should be the configuration of the processor that is compatible for more than 10-15 years...(I mean, a future version 22.04LTS).  I know we can't say about future...but a possible one.

I am an ordinary user. I don't wish to know about multipurpose ones. 2GHz Dual core processor or better...I don't know which are better ones.

If I change the processor, it must be useful at least for 15 years...that is the problem. I don't know whether the problem is with the processor or RAM.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop) doesn't tell about 18.04 LTS

Comment: Whatever spec you choose, it would need to be 64bit and have as much memory and disk space as possible. You don't say what spec you have currently so any reply will have to be extremely subjective.

Comment: Hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @graham: Mine is 1.60 GHz x 2.  It is not suitable. Ram 3GB

Comment: @pomsky: This is about system requirements that suits future versions (at least for 10-15 yrs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: No, that question doesn't mention 18.04, but it does give you ideas of how the flavors of Ubuntu work and which ones are system intensive and which ones are not.  If these are not acceptable to you then consider building your own Linux to match with your hardware.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the question to remove the "shopping" aspect, to avoid having the question closed.

Comment: @Terrance For an "ordinary user" building your own Linux isn't really an option.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I understand that, but also wanting it to "mold" around your life isn't going to happen either.

Comment: @Terrance As I'm reading it, the questioner is having an installation failure and thinks it's 64/32 bit related.  I doubt that's correct, but the "shopping" aspect is obscuring the real issue.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I think it is more of a misunderstanding of the different flavors of Ubuntu and stuck on one type that doesn't work with their hardware, so they are worried about future not working with it too.  Plus, can you predict how it is going to work in 10-15 years?  Can we honestly tell them what Canonical is going to do with their OS?

Comment: @Terrance: Is it not possible to mention the configuration of the processor that might not become obsolete within 10 years?

Comment: @Madhusoodanan How would we know?  I know that a headless (no gui) version of Ubuntu server would run fine on an old Pentium III 450 I have at home, but I know Ubuntu quite well and command line setup.  As far as any GUI goes on it, I would be limited to pretty much LXDE.  There is no way that would run the Unity (Ubuntu), GNOME or KDE desktops on it.  So, the question at hand is not something that we really can answer.

Comment: Hardware recommendation questions are off topic here but you're welcome to ask for it over on [HardwareRecs.SE].

Comment: Please close this question. I have posted a new one.

Answer (score 2):

The current version should run on any 64-bit processor, though it'll run a great deal better with 1.5 GHz clock or faster, and at least 4 GB RAM.  Alternately, some of the "flavors" of Ubuntu (MATE, Budgie, Xubuntu, Lubuntu) still have supported 32-bit versions, while if processor speed is the issue, Xubuntu or Lubuntu will require less from your computer's hardware.

Comment: Mine is 1.60 GHz x 2. It is not suitable. Ram 3GB.  I could install it and open it once or twice.  Copying and Updating was also possible. But not possible now.  The last stage is the problem.  Login screen does not appear. No hard disk problem.

Comment: OS type is 32-bit only.

Comment: Any dual core I'm aware of should be 64-bit capable.  Have you tried downloading and installing the current 64-bit ISO?

Comment: Yes.  I downloaded and installed 18.04 LTS.  But doesn't work properly.  I believe the problem is because it is a 32 bit OS

Comment: @Madhusoodanan: I agree with Zeiss Ikon that your CPU likely support 64-bit Linux. If you want to go into that I recommend that you [open a new question](/questions/ask) and describe how *exactly* you tried to install and run Ubuntu, what you expected to happen and what happened instead including all encountered error or warning messages.

Comment: @David Foerster: Thank you.  I shall open a new question