# My system is slow. What commands can I use to help determine what the problem is?

Tags: performance

My system is considerably slow and I have no idea why and no idea what information I can provide to help determine the cause. What basic trouble shooting can I do to obtain and provide useful information about what the problem might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are commands that you can issue and edit into your post that will be useful in helping you determine what your problem is. As Rinzwind suggests [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068209/system-is-running-increadibly-slow-why-can-this-be#comment1751099_1068209) `top -o %CPU | head -n12`
 could be useful. Also `grep -i error /var/log/syslog` and `dmesg` can provide useful output. A failing hard drive can also have a major impact on system speed especially in situations where files are being processed or swapping is taking place. It's a good idea to [check the SMART status of your storage devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1) on occasion. Another possibility is failing to meet the [minimum requirements](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop) of the version of Ubuntu you have installed as alluded to in [this comment by pa4080.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068290/my-system-is-slow-what-commands-can-i-use-to-help-determine-what-the-problem-is/1068291?noredirect=1#comment1751304_1068291)

If the problem is slow booting, `systemd-analyze blame` can also provide useful information.

Comment: +1 for the possible hard disk issue. Insufficient RAM with Gnome/Unity also could be possible issue. Instead of `top` I would suggest `htop` that allows to sort the column by one click of the mouse