# KDE 18.04 takes too much time to start

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I have been using kde for long time (I am current in **kde 18.04**), but lately. It is taking too much time to start. When I enter password, I most watch up to ***1min 15s*** before it show my desktop. I have tried the command line : systemd-analyze and this is the results:

```
dmx@dmx:/var/tmp$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 4.625s (kernel) + 11.727s (userspace) = 16.353s
graphical.target reached after 11.709s in userspace
```

When I tried

```
dmx@dmx:/var/tmp$ systemd-analyze blame
          6.921s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          6.554s docker.service
          2.185s mysql.service
          1.422s mpd.service
          1.328s networking.service
          1.288s dev-sda1.device
          1.258s xrdp.service
          1.233s keyboard-setup.service
          1.166s vmware.service
          1.120s networkd-dispatcher.service
          1.107s libvirtd.service
           930ms xrdp-sesman.service
           904ms NetworkManager.service
           888ms ModemManager.service
           784ms accounts-daemon.service
           734ms vmware-USBArbitrator.service
           632ms grub-common.service
           617ms udisks2.service
           614ms snapd.service
           582ms vmware-workstation-server.service
           571ms apport.service
           504ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           482ms apache2.service
           388ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
           386ms lm-sensors.service
           385ms systemd-logind.service
           378ms smartmontools.service
           375ms thermald.service
           373ms sysstat.service
           370ms rsyslog.service
           338ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
           336ms apparmor.service
           294ms virtualbox.service
           275ms teamviewerd.service
           251ms bluetooth.service
           247ms virtualbox-guest-utils.service
           246ms packagekit.service
           246ms avahi-daemon.service
           194ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           178ms vpnagentd.service
           167ms systemd-modules-load.service
           162ms ssh.service
           162ms systemd-resolved.service
           160ms polkit.service
           151ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           146ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           142ms setvtrgb.service
          6.921s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          6.554s docker.service
          2.185s mysql.service
          1.422s mpd.service
          1.328s networking.service
          1.288s dev-sda1.device
          1.258s xrdp.service
          1.233s keyboard-setup.service
          1.166s vmware.service
          1.120s networkd-dispatcher.service
          1.107s libvirtd.service
           930ms xrdp-sesman.service
           904ms NetworkManager.service
           888ms ModemManager.service
           784ms accounts-daemon.service
           734ms vmware-USBArbitrator.service
           632ms grub-common.service
           617ms udisks2.service
           614ms snapd.service
           582ms vmware-workstation-server.service
           571ms apport.service
           504ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           482ms apache2.service
           388ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
           386ms lm-sensors.service
           385ms systemd-logind.service
           378ms smartmontools.service
           375ms thermald.service
           373ms sysstat.service
           370ms rsyslog.service
           338ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
           336ms apparmor.service
           294ms virtualbox.service
           275ms teamviewerd.service
           251ms bluetooth.service
           247ms virtualbox-guest-utils.service
           246ms packagekit.service
           246ms avahi-daemon.service
           194ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           178ms vpnagentd.service
           167ms systemd-modules-load.service
           162ms ssh.service
           162ms systemd-resolved.service
           160ms polkit.service
           151ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           146ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           142ms setvtrgb.service
           134ms ebtables.service
           134ms lvm2-monitor.service
           126ms systemd-rfkill.service
           124ms sddm.service
           118ms systemd-journald.service
           114ms dev-hugepages.mount
           113ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           112ms upower.service
           107ms systemd-user-sessions.service
           102ms snapd.seeded.service
           101ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           100ms dev-mqueue.mount
           100ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
            96ms pppd-dns.service
            94ms rtkit-daemon.service
            92ms apache-htcacheclean.service
            87ms wpa_supplicant.service
            86ms colord.service
            81ms qemu-kvm.service
            66ms libvirt-guests.service
            65ms ufw.service
            65ms blk-availability.service
            54ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            54ms kerneloops.service
            44ms systemd-random-seed.service
            42ms systemd-udevd.service
            40ms user@1000.service
            40ms dns-clean.service
            34ms console-setup.service
            34ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
            32ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
            31ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-fcb65fe0\x2dc825\x2d4eac\x2d8e1f\x2d0dc8955af7e7.swap
            30ms plymouth-read-write.service
            29ms systemd-sysctl.service
            28ms resolvconf.service
            26ms docker.socket
            26ms hddtemp.service
            20ms sendmail.service
            17ms alsa-restore.service
            15ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
            14ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
            12ms plymouth-quit.service
             8ms ureadahead-stop.service
             5ms openvpn.service
             3ms snapd.socket
             2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             2ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             2ms gdm3.service
```

as you can see here, some systems services seems to start twice.

Any idea why this is the case and how to solve this ?

Comment: After it finally starts, does your machine work properly or is it sluggish?

Comment: @DKBose it works normally,  but sometimes I find it slow since I have 16 GB RAM and 512 SSD

Comment: You might find [this post useful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068290/my-system-is-slow-what-commands-can-i-use-to-help-determine-what-the-problem-is)