# wich version of ubuntu is best suited for a pentium 4?

Tags: compatibility

hello i found an old pentium 4 in my garage and i would like  to ask wich version of ubuntu is the best suited for a pentium 4 because i woul like to try ubuntu.

the pc have:
3gb of Ram,
40gb Harddrive,
2.3 ghz processor,

than you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you tell us? This is the generic answer:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop but what you accept as "best suited" is up to you to decide.

Comment: The best answers is you try them on your hardware; as you can 'try' without installing (you boot the ISO when expanded to a usb-thumb-drive).  Some versions (esp. GNOME & UNITY) have requirements of your graphic card (you didn't specify), let alone requirements of cpu (x86/x86_64/pae..), and your wants/desires/wanted-programs etc - why not try for yourself, or just read the documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/) or [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/).

Both are described as *lightweigth* distributions and a quick search with Google found some success stories on running both of them with PCs of similar specs to yours.

Comment: Modern Ubuntu-MATE (ie. 18.04 & 18.10) no longer call themselves lightweight.  The move from GTK+2 to GTK+3 increased its system requirements causing them to drop ' lightweight'.  Lubuntu 18.04 & below still use GTK+2, as does Xubuntu 18.04 (though it's moving towards GTK+3, but hadn't completed move at 18.04)

Comment: I can recommend Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS. I'm running it on some Prescotts with 2-4 Gb of RAM.