# Does Intel Pentium Quad Core N5000 processor, 1.10 GHz suitable for UBUNTU 18.04.3 LTS installation and reasonable performance?

Tags: 18.04

I am using HP15 074tu laptop. Processor is Core i3 4005U 1.70 GHz *4. I am using UBUNTU 18.04.3 LTS and it is working fine.

I want to know if any other laptop with intel Pentium 1.10 GHz processor support UBUNTU 18.04.3 LTS  in same way as my present laptop.

[image]

Comment: @Pilot6 it does not answer my question.. It is saying “try it out”.. I don’t have software knowledge to try it... I do not want to buy something that is clearly out of the specifications necessary for 18.04 or more

Comment: Shopping recommendations and questions for opinions are off-topic at this site.

Comment: @Pilot6 It is not shopping question. I was asking if any computer with that specifications can handle Ubuntu or not..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop  Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, I think I get some idea... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Lenovo 81D100HXIN will be able to run Ubuntu smoothly.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give some reference that says it will be ab,e to run Ubuntu smoothly...