# Ubuntu: How much drive space does it need?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, emmc

I have a HP Stream 14. It only has a 32 GB hard drive. An eMMC, so,I can’t remove it to upgrade.

Windows took up most of the 32 GB, so I thought to put Linux on it. I’ve made the bootable USB with Ubuntu 18.04,and tried it out.

Now, I want to install it onto my internal drive, but it says it needs 30GB, which seems a bit excessive.

Should I just pick one of the lighter distros, like Mint or Mate? Or can I stick with regular Ubuntu?

Comment: have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop) it may help you choose

Comment: Where are you seeing 30GB? The only place I know that wanted 30GB was wubi, which has not been supported since 2012. A full install is a lot less, even with lots of applications. But data or large games can quickly consume space. You also can do a full install to a flash drive, although life is not real long depending on use.

Comment: 32GBs plenty of space for installing, but suggest getting an external drive for placing the home partition and/or a data partition if you think you will download a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0):

1. Straight-up Ubuntu with GNOME3 is drive-space-absorbent; Ubuntu [Flavours](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) less so. Want a lighter, smaller OS? Well, there's [Kubuntu](https://www.kubuntu.org/), [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/), [Ubuntu Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/), [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/), and especially [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/), all supported here. (Mint, bless their hearts, has diverged so much we don't support it here.) Pick a Flavour, any Flavour, and you will have oodles of room, even on the 32.
2. Now that Canonical has seized upon [Snaps](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/basic-snap-usage#0), OS drives are filling up rapidly. If you don't use them and install from other sources, the OS drive doesn't fill up as rapidly.
3. eMMCs CAN be upgraded. I threw a 500GB eMMC into a Thinkpad T420. Works great with two different OS on it as well as a /home partition chock full of Stuff. Bought it on [Big River Trading Outfit](https://www.amazon.com/emmc-storage/s?k=emmc%20storage).
4. If you need more storage, see item 3 above, or add a [tiny](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22SanDisk%20Cruzer%20Fit%22&oq=%22SanDisk%20Cruzer%20Fit%22) USB drive or [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22+Samsung+Flash+Drive+Fit%22) which does not stick very far out of the socket for convenience, and leave it there.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does indeed recommend 25GB of hard-drive space as ['Recommended Minimum System Requirements'](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).

Well I have an Acer c720p chromebook here with an 32GB hard-drive. I have a full Ubuntu installation on it with additional software. Still have about 20GB of disk space free for my data.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 just need 25 GB.

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/04/ubuntu-18-04-download-release-features

If you want more lighter Ubuntu distro, I will suggest you XUbuntu 22.04 LTS. It just need 20GB recommended storage or minimum 8.6GB.

https://xubuntu.org/requirements/

It is light weight and highly customizable.
https://itsfoss.com/customize-xfce/