# Boot for the first time

Tags: boot, networking, 18.04, system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.  The instructions I followed told me to get my boot version from http://unetbootin.gethub.io.  It told me to put the boot software on a memory stick ... which I did.  It then to me to boot from the memory stick ... which I did.  The next step was select whether to run Ubuntu from the memory stick. I got the error message "Failed to Start Network Time Synchronization".  The only other thing I could think to try was to load Ubuntu on my PC.  I got the same error message.  The software did not change the software on my PC.  My PC is 64-bit; however it's a 2012 version. I'm wondering if it's too slow to run the 18.04 Live x64 version of Ubuntu.

Comment: We try to keep things in bite-sized easily answered chunks here, but you've got 2  questions I can see: 1) How should I install, & 2) Can I install 18.04? I've answered #1. No. 2 depends on info you have given, such as CPU, RAM, & drive speed. It's not impractical on many ca. 2012 machines to run 18.04; I run it on 2  vintage 2010 ThinkPads. However, the official answer to 2) is at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements with detail at https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop Want to know more? Ask!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official process from https://tutorials.ubuntu.com

Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download , or for a supported lighter and faster 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours .

Check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 .

Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0

or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .

Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0.