# Can my Lenovo IdeaPad run Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, lenovo, system-requirements

I have Windows 10 on my computer and want to install Xubuntu on it because Windows 10 is working too slowly. I am a beginner and haven't done anything with the operating system yet. Please tell can my computer run Xubuntu and also how to install it. I also want to store Windows 10 on a flash drive so that I can use it.

Specs:

- Lenovo Ideapad MIIX 300-10IBY
- Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU Z3735F@ 1.33GHz 64-bit
- RAM: 2GB
- 28GB disk storage including Windows 10

If any additional information is needed please comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) or [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop) and [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you have a 4+ GB flash drive, you can install xubuntu on this type of hardware.
Hopefully this tutorial will help you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPgI3Kgc8RE
If you have another flash drive then you could store windows 10 but that needs more storage. If you want a clean version of windows 10 installed in the flash drive then here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0YmSdr6K2s
16+ GB flash drive is recommended for this task.

Comment: Can I install Ubuntu and not XUbuntu

Comment: Yes you can but it has to be 18.04 or older.

Comment: You can link to a source, but you should fully explain your solution here.  Our Q&A format is designed to be all about getting answers and reducing chit-chat or distraction.  In general, youtube links are not very helpful. We cannot easily verify the source information without suffering through a *youtuber*  https://askubuntu.com/tour | https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Can it not run 20 ubuntu. What if after booting my computer to ubuntu and not installing windows on a pen drive if I again want to run windows I have to purchase a new one?