# Install Ubuntu 20.04 on Razer Blade 15 2020 with NVIDIA® GeForce RTX™ 2070 with Max-Q (8 GB GDDR6 VRAM)

Tags: system-installation, nvidia-geforce

I want to buy this computer for machine/deep learning purposes and want to install ubuntu on it.

https://www.razer.com/de-de/gaming-laptops/Razer-Blade-15/RZ09-03287G22-R3G1?gclid=Cj0KCQiAifz-BRDjARIsAEElyGLmqgYnAfNB_hEk8pwZhOsm-oTDMZS4p0SzJcF9A9gOOGvautB9xscaAgT9EALw_wcB

Does anyone have experience with it? Is there some hardware element, which will make me problems with the installation?

Comment: If you’re going to be doing deep learning or other scientific efforts with a Linux machine, it might make more sense to get one that comes with Ubuntu (or another distro of your choice) out of the box. This will reduce any downtime and give you the support and confidence you need that the machine is trustworthy. Have you looked at [Tuxedo](https://www.tuxedocomputers.com/en/Linux-Hardware/Linux-Notebooks/Alle.tuxedo#!#1885,1886)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 5):

In case you haven't bought anything by now:

I bought the Razer Blade 15 (but the 2021 version with the RTX 3080) and had a few minor problems installing everything. But I wrote everything down and you can find it here:

https://etiennemueller.github.io/razer-blade-data-science/

I hope this helps, if you have any other questions, don't hesitate asking.

Answer (score 3):

On the Blade 15 2020 base model there are issues. After putting the machine on suspend and waking up it starts to go into suspend mode all the time until a reboot. This happens no matter if you use the intel/nvidia or hybrid GPU mode.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Razer Blade 15 with RTX 3080 from 2021.
Some known issues and how to solve are also documented here:

https://rolandguelle.github.io/razer-blade-stealth-linux/ubuntu-18-04.html

Most of those worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04

I updated to kernel 5.10.0 because wifi is not supported with previous kernels.

The polychromatic tool works perfectly and the suspension is working as well. There is just one thing that doesn't work nice for me, which is the touchpad after resuming from suspension. In that case, the touchpad is very laggy and doesn't respond well. I tried several things like restarting the i2c_hid module. It's not a big thing, but if anyone knows a fix for that, would be appreciated.