# Can I use Ubuntu 20.4 with 1.9GHz processor?

Tags: system-requirements

Can I use Ubuntu 20.4 on a laptop with a 2GB ram and 1.9GHz processor? It is a x64 bit processor with 2 cores. I have not tried anything due to financial deficits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: If you open several programs simultaneously (especially a browser) the memory would be the issue. I would suggest you to use a less resource hungry variant like Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: @user300458 the answers of the possible duplicate you suggested mostly talk about 18.04 and 16.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407/)

Answer (score 5):

According to [the Help Site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements), that 2GB of RAM will not be fun.

**Minimum Requirements for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:**

- 2 GHz dual core processor
- 4 GiB RAM (system memory)
- 25 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but consider a LiveCD for an alternative approach)
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
- Internet access is helpful

You may want to take a look at [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/), which is a flavour of Ubuntu that uses the XFCE desktop rather than Gnome.

**Minimum Requirements for Xubuntu 20.04 LTS:**

- a 1.5Ghz Dual Core processor
- 2 GB of memory
- 20 GB of storage space

Alternatively, there's [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/), which is an excellent distribution for a lot of people.

**Minimum Requirements for Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS:**

- a 1GHz Pentium M (or similar) CPU
- 1GB of RAM
- 8GB of storage

There are many other low-requirement versions of Ubuntu (and other Linux distributions) available to suit just about any use case you might have.

Hope this helps,