# Please help me install Nvidia drivers

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics

please help and please explain it like I'm five. It's been a long time since I've done any Ubuntu computer tasks.

So I have dug out my old HP ISTART-D2314 computer.
The specs are

Memory - 1.7 GiB
Processor - Intel Pentium E2160 @ 1.80GHz

It has this Nvidia installed.
NVIDIA GeForce 7050 / NVIDIA nForce 610i

It currently has 14.04 LTS installed and it is happily using the Nvidia proprietary drivers.

I've burnt 20.04 LTS to a disc as I was planning to upgrade but when booting from the live CD the screen is pixelated and Is pretty much unusable, I can just about manage to get to the software update page but there are no proprietary drivers available.

My questions,

are my current driver's no longer supported for 20.04?

If they are how can I install what I need.

And how do I know what drivers I need?

And on another note, would 20.04 run ok on my current machine or should I just forget about the Nvidia drivers and go with something lighter like lubuntu instead?

Thanks :-)

Comment: 1.7GB of memory suggests that this might be a 32-bit system. On your 14.04 system, please run `uname -i` and share the complete output with us. If 64-bit ("x86_64"), that's very small RAM -- [most flavors of Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795) require a minimum of 4GB RAM.

Comment: It's 64bit. Sorry I forgot to add that. :-)