# Can I use Ubuntu on an old PC?

Tags: 14.04

I would like to know if I can install Ubuntu on an old computer

Their characteristics are:

Intel core i3 380M 2.53 GHZ processor
2 GB ram memory
320GB hard drive

Comment: Questions like these are not accepted on AskUbuntu. Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop for a generic answer. Ubuntu is free so you can download it and put it on an USB and try out if it works. The question does also depend on how well you are versed with operating systems, dual booting if applicable. Also: 14.04 is no longer a valid version.

Comment: Check laptop specs. CPU [supports](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/50178/intel-core-i3-380m-processor-3m-cache-2-53-ghz.html) 8 Gb. So if possible buy more RAM and SSD, then install Xubuntu or MATE here.

Comment: Probably not Ubuntu, but a lightweight flavor will work well. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie  I have Kubuntu  on a 2006 Toshiba laptop with 1.5GB of RAM. Bit slow but usable.

Answer (score 1):

Since the system is equipped with 2 GB of RAM only, you should use a 32-bit operating system which is not supported any more.

A 64-bit system will use approximately 600-700 MB of memory, leaving approximately 1.3 GB available for the user. If this is enough for you, go ahead and try a light flavour, like **Lubuntu** or **Xubuntu** for example. Maybe you'd like to add some more memory before you install a 64-bit system though.