# Which version of Ubuntu can I use on an old laptop?

Tags: system-installation

I have a old laptop with the following specifications:

- AMD Brazos Dual core 1Ghz
- 4GB ram

Will my laptop be able to run Ubuntu?

If yes then which version will I need to install?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) and closely related: [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: I would opt for a *lighter* flavor of Ubuntu over main Ubuntu.  The *flavors* have shorter lives for LTS releases (3 years not 5 years), but I'm running the current *development* release on a 2009 dell box fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to ubuntu for a solution then consider [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/).

It is an official derivative of Ubuntu. The only difference between other Ubuntu OS's is that it uses the MATE desktop environment.

You can follow the guide to installing MATE on an ageing laptop [here](https://www.instructables.com/Installing-Ubuntu-Mate-on-an-OldAgeing-Laptop/)

It works well on better spec machines too (including v21.04) and ideally suited to those with less heavy desktop requirements.

You can look through the MATE guide [here](https://guide.ubuntu-mate.org/)