# What is the min. size of the Hard Drive to install Ubuntu? I am a new user

Tags: system-installation

I have install the Microsoft App. Ubuntu 20.04LTS on a HP Pavilion dv7 Notebook PC Processor is  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz   2.20 GHz  8.00 Gb with 1TB SSD . I have Windows 10 Pro installed and need to know what else is needed to run on top of Windows.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit your question and add if you want to install the standalone Ubuntu desktop, the standalone Ubuntu server, or the WSL Ubuntu app that runs within Windows 10. If the last one, do you plan to use WSL 1 or WSL 2?

Comment: To clarify, you did not mean a dual-boot system right? From then on: do you mean Windows-Subsystem-for-Linux (WSL), or do you mean running Ubuntu in a virtual machine, like in Oracle's Virtualbox? If the latter, you need Virtualbox too.

Comment: Windows- Subsystem-for-Linux knot dual-boot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the documentation from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and [the Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/p/ubuntu-2004-lts/9n6svws3rx71?activetab=pivot:regionofsystemrequirementstab), you will need:

- Windows 10 version 16237.0 or higher
- ARM64 or x64-based CPU
- Keyboard
- Mouse *(probably unnecessary)*

Speaking from experience, you will want to run WSL on a machine that has at least 8GB of RAM and 30GB of free space. The hardware specifications you outlined for your HP notebook are more than enough.

Do note that the initial installation is just a few gigabytes in size (450MB download / ~3GB installed), but a WSL container will not (yet) auto-shrink as files are deleted. So make sure that there's enough free storage space on your machine to handle this limitation.