# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installation on Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15ALC // Alternative would be Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, 22.04, lts, ideapad

I am planning to get new hardware for a customer but I am not 100% sure if the hardware Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15ALC is fully supported from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, what about Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.