# Web browser launches but does not show on screen

Tags: firefox, chromium, browser

I have just installed Ubuntu on my machine and when I try to open Firefox, the browser runs but no window appears. Same goes for Chromium, and when trying to run Opera, only a black window appears.

It appears as though the browser "works" in a sense that the cursor changes when hovering over where the address bar should be and also I can close the browser by clicking on the top right corner. It's just that the UI does not show properly on screen. For Firefox and Chromium, it appears that the background shakes when I move the cursor around until I close the browser.

When I tried to use Firefox on the Try Ubuntu on my installation disk before installing, it works fine and I can browse the web, but the problem appears once I had Ubuntu installed on the machine.

This is my first time trying to use Ubuntu and Linux OS in general.

Ubuntu 22.04.1 desktop amd64

I use an old dinosaur from 2007:

- Intel Core 2 Duo E6550 2.33 GHz
- 5 GB RAM
- Integrated graphics

Comment: I've edited my question to add more details

Comment: I use ~8 c2d type devices in QA (*Quality Assurance*) testing though rarely using *onboard* graphics, eg. `hp dc7700 (c2d-e6320, 5gb, nvidia quadro nvs 290)`, `dell [optiplex] 745 (c2d-6600, 6gb, amd/ati radeon rv516/x1300/x1550)`, `dell [optiplex] 755 (c2d-e6850, 5gb, amd/ati radeon rv516/x1300/x1550)` etc and on older hardware like those I'd recommend a *lighter flavor* like Lubuntu, Xubuntu etc than the main Ubuntu Desktop.  You can use a command like `sudo lshw -C display` to display details of display/graphics hardware; the -C display limits results to that class)

Comment: I followed your recommendation on using Xubuntu instead of Ubuntu and it works! I'm sticking with it from now on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use ~8 c2d type devices in QA (Quality Assurance) testing though rarely using onboard graphics, eg. (c2d-?6??? include)

- `hp dc7700 (c2d-e6320, 5gb, nvidia quadro nvs 290)`,
- `dell [optiplex] 745 (c2d-6600, 6gb, amd/ati radeon rv516/x1300/x1550)`,
- `dell [optiplex] 755 (c2d-e6850, 5gb, amd/ati radeon rv516/x1300/x1550)`

and on older hardware like those I'd recommend a *lighter flavor* like Lubuntu, Xubuntu etc than the main Ubuntu Desktop.

*If you intended to use Qt5 applications, Lubuntu would be my choice, if you were wanting to use GTK applications then I'd use Xubuntu, especially with limited RAM available (2GB, 3GB..). Though with 5GB I'd also consider tastes as well (ie. which desktop will make you happy)*

Comment: More details can be found at https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop