# Ubuntu Installation issue in Virtual Box 6.0

Tags: server, virtualbox, system-requirements

I am a student of networking. I have been using Virtual box for my projects to learn different networking. Today I am working on a University project and I am trying to install Ubuntu in [Virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) but I am getting an error that my memory is not enough. I have a question what is the ideal memory size to install Ubuntu?

My host machine is using MS Window 7 Ultimate 64-bit. And I am trying to install Ubuntu on guest machine. My host computer has https://www.allhdd.com/samsung-m393a4k40cb2-ctd-memory/ (32GB RAM) installed which should be more than enough memory to run Window 7 on the physical machine and an Ubuntu guest OS in VirtualBox.

Comment: My host machine is using MS Window 7 Ultimate 64 Bit. And I am trying to install Ubuntu on guest machine. My machine has https://www.allhdd.com/samsung-m393a4k40cb2-ctd-memory/ memory installed.

Comment: You've provided no specifics as to what Ubuntu product/release you're asking about; most details however will be found in documentation - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements - but don't forget Oracle have said `virtualbox` can misbehave if insufficient RAM is allocated to VMs, which is a user-created issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Answer (score 1):

The minimum and recommended memory requirements for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server are listed in [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407/).

As a rule of thumb the base memory allocated to the guest OS should not exceed 50% of the available physical RAM. If you are running multiple guest OSs at the same time, the base memory allocated to all of the currently running guest OSs together should not exceed 50% of the available physical RAM. If you assign too much memory to the virtual machine, the machine may might not be able to start.

To change the amount of virtual memory allocated to a specific guest OS in VirtualBox follow these steps.

1. In VirtualBox select the Ubuntu guest OS.
2. In the VirtualBox toolbar click gear-shaped Settings icon ⚙️.
3. In the left pane select *System*.
4. Select the *Motherboard* tab.
5. Move the *Base Memory* slider which controls the amount of memory provided to the virtual machine.

   [image]
6. Click the *OK* button in the lower right corner.