# Will my laptop sustain Ubuntu?

Tags: laptop

I want to try a Linux-based OS so I am hoping to try the Ubuntu distro. Can anyone tell me if my lap can handle it? It is an old laptop (8-10 years old) with the following specs:

- Processor:Intel(R) Celeron(R) 2957U @ 1.40GHz 1.40 GHz
- RAM: 4 GB
- Hard disk: 512 GB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) and [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop) and [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0):

That laptop is better than my laptop, and the CPU is similar, I tried installing Ubuntu on it, it worked, except the touch pad drivers don't work quite right though, and it takes forever to start up (I think it has to do with me turning off fast boot thinking it messes with Ubuntu like secureboot apparently does), So I think if you have fast boot enabled, it will work pretty well,