# Which version for Asus ee pc

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 12.03 on my ASUS EE, but ut isn't supported any more. Which ubuntu version would run on an ASUS EE netbook and is still supported?

Comment: Ubuntu is free of charge. Canonical supplies a live session you can try and see for yourself if it works. It only takes time and it is better to form your own opinion (what you deem unworkable might be decent to me :) ). Mind that 32-bit systems are no longer supported; you'll need to look outside of Ubuntu for an OS. Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop for a list of optons and their requirement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) Start with this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/50184/

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 12.03 (2012-March) release so you've likely got a forgery,  OR you have installed something different to that, so I'd check your details.

Comment: It's actually 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is EOL thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 12.04 ESM was in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/03/15/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-reaches-end-of-life-on-april-28-2017/

Comment: As I've stated before, I used an asus eepc in *Quality Assurance* testing of Ubuntu releases up to the last that would run on my 32-bit only device; ie. release of August 2020, that was supported fully until April 2021 with part support April 2023.  Some later asus eePCs will use all *modern* releases (*though run best with a lighter desktop in my view*); the CPU in your box plus firmware will dictate this (my n270 cpu now runs Debian GNU/Linux) as components changed over asus eePC production.