Official pages mentioning system requirements for official Ubuntu flavours
I have a 11.6 inch Asus laptop with following configuration
OS: Windows 10 Home
Processor: Intel Celeron N4500 Processor 1.1 Ghz (4M Cache, upto 2.8 GHz, 2 cores)
Memory: 4GB DDR4 onboard, Memory Max upto 4 GB
Storage: 128 GB M.2 NVMe PCIe 3.0 2280 SSD (Supports upgrade upto  2 TB M.2 NVMe SSD)

I want to install Ubuntu on it.
Reading about latest (24.04) Ubuntu Desktop edition at https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop#system-requirements found that it is not suitable for my machine and exploring on web I found that for machines with lower configurations official Ubuntu flavours (https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours) should be used.
Checking out the websites of Xubuntu, Kubuntu and Lubuntu it is only on xubuntu website I could find the system requirements page at https://xubuntu.org/requirements/ and looking at the recommended specs I came to conclusion it is not suitable for my machine.
Checking the website of Kubuntu at https://kubuntu.org/ and Lubuntu at https://lubuntu.me/ I couldn't find the system requirements for installing them.
Are there any official pages which mentions them so that one can go through them and decide whether they are suitable for a particular machine or not?
Checking out website of Ubuntu Budgie at https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads/ following is mentioned at the time of writing this

Ideal for computers with: 4GB or more of RAM, 64-bit capable Intel and
AMD processors, UEFI PCs booting in CSM mode, Modern Intel-based Apple
Macs

Checking out Edubuntu at https://www.edubuntu.org no system requirements information available.
Checking out Ubuntu Cinnamon at https://ubuntucinnamon.org/ no system requirements information available.
Checking out Ubuntu Mate I could find System Requirements information at https://ubuntu-mate.org/about/requirements/.
All that said and shared my last question is which of the available flavours would one recommend for my machine config? I want to primarily use my machine for note-taking purpose and doing some scripting in Ruby language.
Thank you.

Lubuntu haven't provided minimum requirements since 18.04 or the last release using the LXDE Desktop, as was written about back in 2018, ie. https://lubuntu.me/taking-a-new-direction/   I continued to use machines with 1GB of RAM, single-core CPU in my own Quality Assurance testing up to 19.04, then upgraded it to 2GB & dual-core for later releases... but I still think that's pretty meaningless; as I use low-resources machine differently to the current 2017 machine which has far more resources...

FYI:   Lubuntu is the lightest of the flavors out of the box... however on a low-resources machine I'd not use the hardware to decide what flavor I used anyway...   I'd firstly work out what apps you'll use and your actual runtime requirements, which is rather critical if your machine is low-resource in regards RAM.. as you want the desktop & the user-apps to share resources as much as possible... Sure if you spare resources tastes can come into it, but start by working what you'll use it for, then select apps, from which you can know libs/toolkits required & go from there!

@guiverc Thanks for your quick response. Before posting the question I did came across https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop but the answers are quite old. Ofcourse I would not consider them completely outdated but I believe having official pages motivates the end-user to take a better decision.

@guiverc w.r.t https://askubuntu.com/questions/1518545/official-pages-mentioning-system-requirements-for-official-ubuntu-flavours?noredirect=1#comment2667017_1518545 so you are recommending me to choose the flavour by experimenting with them. Is that correct? If yes, based on your experience and the machine config I have shared do you mind sharing your personal recommend to me to start with? As I said my primary goal with this machine is note-taking and secondary doing general Ruby scripting. Thanls.

You're off-topic on this site asking for opinions as to what we consider the best given your hardware, as if you read https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask this is a Question and Answer site where the Question is the problem to be solved in Answer form, with questions seeking opinions being better suited for Forums & not Q&A sites. https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the address of Ubuntu Forums, and you'll hopefully note "there is no actual problem to be solved" is listed as example...  You mention ruby programming... if doing that using vim & CLI or using a IDE to code is very different!

@guiverc Understood your point and sorry about being off-topic and Thank you for sharing your insights on my original question.

Anybody finding this question relevant to he/r I would recommend to view detailed discussion in https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2498694. Thanks.
